# How to implement a remote control application?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Hi all,

Now I want to implement a remote control application, then I google it.  I found **SendMessage**, **FindWindow** and **GetDesktopWindow** can help me do something basic. I write some test code in Visual Studio 2010 Experess, then run the application in Win7. Code looks like:

::SendMessage(::GetDesktopWindow(), WM_MOUSEMOVE, (WPARAM)0, LPARAM(0));

I just want to send a message to the desktop and move the cursor the position (0, 0). However, the cursor doesn't move at all.

I think it's the cursor movement that generates the WM_MOUSEMOVE message. what I want is just oppsite. So what should I do, can any SDK API help me finish the cursor movement and the click operation of every kind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[SetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648394%28VS.85%29.aspx) is what you're looking for, I think.

> Moves the cursor to the specified screen coordinates. If the new coordinates are not within the screen rectangle set by the most recent [ClipCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function call, the system automatically adjusts the coordinates so that the cursor stays within the rectangle.

Comment: Yes, SetCursorPos is pretty good for me. Then how can I simulate the mouse click event? Of course, I have send WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP events to the desktop with the handler found by FindDesktopWindow.